# How can I track currently available maps

Tags: rainbow-six-siege

For a month or two now some maps were competently removed from play and the total pool was reduced from I believe 20 to 13. For few days now the previously removed maps are back and some other maps are removed. I can't seem to find any notice about this and what are the current active maps, when the next rotation will happen, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Rotation will happen every month with 4 maps getting in the Map Pool and 4 maps get out of it. This was introduced, with the reduction to 14 maps in the Casual Map Pool and 12 in the Ranked and Unranked Map Pool, with the new Ember Rise Season.

The current Ranked Map Pool are:
Canal, Oregon, Clubhouse, Consulate, Bank, Chalet, Kafe Dostoyevsky, Border, Skyscraper, Coast, Villa, Outback.

In the Casual pool this are included to and the following are being added:
House, Plane, Favela, Tower

Removed are the following:
Skyscraper, Hereford, Fortress, Chalet

These are the links to the Announcements:
[Current Map rotation](https://www.ubisoft.com/en-us/game/rainbow-six/siege/news-updates/2GlmTIRxZ7TFnCiE0mBLLc/dev-blog-casual-playlist-rotation)
[Patchnotes to Ember Rise important part at Map Rotation](https://rainbow6.ubisoft.com/siege/en-us/game-info/seasons/emberrise/index.aspx)

To keep track of it you should visit the [Rainbow 6 Siege Home page](https://rainbow6.ubisoft.com/siege/en-US/home/index.aspx) after every update, since there isn't any an in-game Announcement on Map Pool Changes, and look in the News Section for Map Pool Changes.